# Android SurfaceView vs GLSurfaceView for wallpaper-style background

Tags: android, opengl-es, background, surfaceview

I need to create a game for one of my projects. The game is not a grafic game but I still want it to have nice appearance (maybe 3D background look).
I thought I would use a diferent technique than just to load the background through an xml file. I want to create a surface view with a nice texture background (what I would like is one similar to the live wall papers). I know there is the rendererscript but I apparently it doesn't work on apis level lower than 11??? I would like to target api level 7 or 8.

Here is what I planned to do something like that:

```
    mView = new BasicGLSurfaceView(getApplication());

    View inflatedView=View.inflate(this, R.layout.title, null);
    View inflatedView2=View.inflate(this, R.layout.buttons, null);

    setContentView(mView);
    this.getWindow().addContentView(inflatedView, 
            new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    this.getWindow().addContentView(inflatedView2, 
            new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

I was wondering which way is the best:
use open GLSurfaceView or just normal SurfaceView and Canvas. Which one is faster and will look nicer?
Could you please advice me on the best solution to implement?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Canvas is simpler, and it's fast, but it doesn't support 3D drawing. Since you said that you might want to do 3D, you would want to use the GLSurfaceView and OGLES. Canvas can often outperform OpenGL for 2D drawing.